# How to update Shiny Datatable after Submit with Filtered Visible Data based on Reactive?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

This is my first question to SO, and I'll try to be as brief and clear as possible.

I'm modifying one version of a basic Shiny CRUD made available by Dean Attali (to whom: thank you) for research purposes.  To get there, I've generated a toy MRE (see below) that exhibits the main behaviors I'm trying to achieve.

1. User filters displayed data predicated on a reactive (refreshData() based on input$item_used)
2. User can add or delete new entries (saveData(), deleteData())
3. User can click on rows and see reactive changes dynamically via a DT::dataTableOutput.

My problem is the following: if a user adds a new entry, and the visible DT data is filtered on one of the two options in the drop-down selection, then the *active DT view does not update*.  Say the user adds a new entry to the 'B' items, with all of and only the 'B' items visible in the table (filtered through the drop-down) -- in order to see the new entry, she would have to select the 'A' items, and then select the 'B' items again, to 'refresh' the table in order to see the new entry.

I know that there is a simple solution here based on reactivity, but I can't seem to identify it.  Your collective help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "item_used", "notes")
data <- data.frame(name = c("Luthien","Aredhel","Beren","Turin"),
                   item_used = c("A","B","A","B"),
                   notes = c("fixed","not broken","almost fixed", "beyond repair"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,

                 selectInput("select_used", "Item Used?", choices = c("", "A","B")),
                 tags$hr(),
                  lapply(1:length(fields), function(x) textInput(fields[x], fields[x])),
                  actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
                 actionButton("delete", "Delete")
  ),
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("maindata", width = 300),
            tags$hr()
             ))),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })

    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })

    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$maindata <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$delete
      input$submit
      refreshData()
    })

    observeEvent(input$maindata_rows_selected, {
      dat <- refreshData()[input$maindata_rows_selected,]
      for(i in 1:length(dat)){
        updateTextInput(session, fields[i], value = unname(dat[i]))
      }

    })

    observeEvent(input$delete,{
      deleteData()
    })

    deleteData <- function(){
      delrow <- row.names(refreshData()[input$maindata_rows_selected,])
      data <- loadData()[-c(as.numeric(delrow)),]
      data <<- data

    }

    loadData <- function(){
      data <- data
      return(data)
    }    

    saveData <- function(data) {
      data <- rbind(loadData(), formData())
      data <<- data
    }

    refreshData <- reactive({
      data <- loadData()
      if(input$select_used == ""){
        data
      } else {
        data[data$item_used == input$select_used, ]
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered my own question, and I'll post this here in the event anyone else may find it of use.  The solution was maddeningly simple.

Rather than define the "refreshed data" as a reactive, it should be a function.  So...

```
 refreshData <- reactive({...})
```

...ought to be...

```
 refreshData <- function(){...}
```

No other changes to the original code are necessary. With the change to refreshData as a function, it is then possible to insert new data (via the input fields) while preserving a filtered view (in DT) based on user input.